# Access control of Azure IoT Edge device management

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Is it possible to restrict management of IoT edge devices by groups or some filtering criteria?

The scenario would be that we have different sites with different edge devices deployed to these sites.  We have a single IoT hub for the organization, is it possible to restrict management of only certain devices within the IoT hub or would we require different IoT hubs by site to do this?

Comment: Is the requirement to restrict only certain users for certain devices?

Comment: @UtkarshPal-MT yes, that is what we are wondering if that level of access control is possible within the IoT edge management perspective.  For example, user1 could configure modules only for device1 and user2 could configure modules only for device2

Comment: please refer https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot-hub-dps-sdks/suggestions/42801026-allow-for-more-granular-access-for-iot-hub-shared